# My Personal Communication iSeries Access for Windows gets disconnected

Tags: disconnect, iseries-navigator

Whenever I call a specific RPG program my Personal Communication client gets disconnected. It was working fine last day but today it has strange behavior rest of the AS400 system is working fine. What could be the reason?

Thanks

Comment: Can it happen due to some network issue? because I am facing this problem with some other callings..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening due to some network slow response. As the program which I was calling was eating up network resources that's why my Personal Communication client was disconnecting continuously. One that day overall network was slower. It didn't happen afterwards.